# NoMethodError in Profiles#show undefined method `about' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently re-working my routes, which leads to a lot of mistakes in my Rails App. I am coming from something like

```
users/:user_id/profiles/id/reviews
```

to

```
/users/:user_id/profile/reviews
```

After registering a user gets redirected (redirect_after_sign_up) to a profile

```
/users/:user_id/profile/new
```

where the user can fill out the form (a allow nested attributes for profile)

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: user_profile_path, method: :post) do |form| %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :street %>
    <%= form.text_area :street %>
  </div>



    <%= fields_for(:profile) do |profile_fields| %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= profile_fields.label :about %>
        <%= profile_fields.text_area :about %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= profile_fields.file_field :avatar %>
        <% profile_fields.label "Profile photo" %>
      </div>

  <% end %>



  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit "Save your profile", class: "btn btn-default" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

After I click submit, these data won't save anywhere. The user also won't get redirected to the #show, as, there are obviously some problems with my profiles controller. Neither #show, nor #create works. Here is the controller

```
    class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    @profile = current_user.profile
    @review = Review.new
    Review.where(profile: @profile) 
  end

  def new
    @user = User.eager_load(:profile).find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def edit
    @profile = @user.profile
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @profile = current_user.build_profile(profile_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user.id), notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user.id), notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1
  # DELETE /profiles/1.json
  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_profile
      @profile = current_user.profile
    end

    def profile_params
      params.permit(:about, :avatar)
    end

    end
```

I really need help adjusting the controller, so it works without a profile_id. Here is the show page, just in case:

```
<% if @profile == current_user.profile  %>
    <strong> Welcome </strong><%= current_user.first_name  %>
<% else  %>
    <strong> This is a profile of </strong><%= @profile.user.first_name  %> <%= @profile.user.last_name  %>
<% end  %>


<p>
  <strong>About:</strong>
  <%= @profile.about %>
</p>


    <strong>Profile image</strong>
    <%= image_tag(url_for(@profile.avatar), style: 'width:50px; height:50px;') %>
</p>

<%= render 'reviews/form' %>

<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
    <%= review.user.first_name %> <%= review.user.last_name %> wrote <small> <%= time_ago_in_words(review.created_at) %> ago </small>
    <p>
        <%= review.content %>
        <br>
        <strong> Rating </strong><%= review.rating %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_profile(current_user.profile) %>
<%= link_to 'Show other profiles', users_path %>


<div class="container">
```

Thank you.
P.S. I tried to work with a ProfileController (single), but this didn't work at all, as the app wouldn't find the controller.

UPDATE:
So, I tried to play with the form, looks like the form won't save neither to profile nor to user. Even if I get rid of the nested attributes, it still doesn't save. This stays unresoled ...

Comment: Can you share us the create action log entries.

Comment: It looks like current_user.profile is nil, can you confirm if this is the case?

Comment: #<User id: 3, email: "nope@mail.com", created_at: "2019-11-27 02:55:35", updated_at: "2019-11-27 02:55:35", first_name: "Kate", last_name: "Schreiber" 
is the current _user, saved to DB, so as far as my knowledge goes, user is not nil

Comment: The create action of the ProfilesController is in the code. Or do you mean smth. else?

Comment: Oh, actually maybe I am wront, since a user should be able to see other users' profile, "@profile = @user.profile" . But this doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

as i can see you're using `fields_for`, so check a structure od params which are send when posting. I suppose they may look like:

```
user: { :street, profile_attributes: { :about, :avatar } }
```

and if yes, you need to change the permitted params method to match what is actually send.
Next advise is to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile` in user model, and use `fields_for` proper way by saving profile in addition to saving user, because current code is little messy (form_for user with fields for profile leading to profile controller).

If you don't wan't to deal with nested attributes you may also rewrite form as `form_for @profile ...`

Comment: you may also want to read more about nested forms: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes

Comment: My coding experience is very short. Could you specify, whyt does excactly mean. I am not even sure, how toch check the passed params. I went to the browser, but I guess it't not the right way to do ... Thank you

Comment: P.S. I already have this: accepts_nested_attributes_for_profile

Comment: in console where you're starting rails, after every request there are logged information about it ex. path, controller, params etc. you can check it there or post here full console output

Comment: Started POST "/users/11/profile" for ::1 at 2019-11-27 06:11:07 -0600
Processing by ProfilesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"some_token", "user"=>{"street"=>"st"}, "profile"=>{"about"=>"ab", "avatar"=>"original.jpg"}, "commit"=>"Save your profile", "user_id"=>"11"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:21

Comment: Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :authenticity_token, :user, :profile, :commit, :user_id
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:25
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:25
  Rendering profiles/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered profiles/_form.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered profiles/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.3ms) 
Profile Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/layouts/_header_rest.html.erb

Comment: `HTML Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"some_token", "user"=>{"street"=>"st"}, "profile"=>{"about"=>"ab", "avatar"=>"original.jpg"}, "commit"=>"Save your profile", "user_id"=>"11"}` 
but you're permitting only `{ :about, :avatar }`. You can see in logs also info about passed but unpermited params. You shoul'd in that case permit profile params by `params.require(:profile).permit(:about, :avatar)`

Comment: Don't I have it here? def profile_params  params.permit(:about, :avatar) end ? I learned I don't need require, in other cases I used it, it would show an error. Also, I tried to adjust my form, but for me it looks like it should be, as profile is nested in user. Thanks you

Comment: If I change it, I get an error ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature
  @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

Comment: TBH, there is a lot of mess there, and it's resulting with issues like that. I can only suppose as I never seen `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature` before. But one thing I'm sure here that form could be written better:
1) You don't need to think about `profile` as nested in user as long as you are posting form to `profiles_controller` not `users_controller` and saving `profile` object - `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `fields_for` will help you save profile attributes or create profile while saving or creating `user`

Comment: 2) You should use require in `permitted_params`. It will ensure you that an object exists in params and also will keep proper structure of params

Comment: I guess the issue is, that in my form I am "updating" the User. Cause if I just  use "form.submit" without my own button text, it states "Update User"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203191/discussion-between-katharina-schreiber-and-blazpie).